# Local macros for subset of observations

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I would like to create a local macro for a subset of my dataset to use for future regressions (see [Some Uses for Macros Outside of Loops](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/stata_prog1.htm) section).

I've started off with code that is along the following lines:

```
quietly reg y x1 x2 x3
local subset if e(sample)
list Unit `subset'
reg y x1 x2 if `subset'
```

`x3` has missing values, so some observations are excluded in the first `reg` command.  The output from the `list` command does indicate that contents of the macro are indeed what I want (`Unit` is a variable that identifies the observation).

Nevertheless, I receive an error message after the last command:

```
if not found
r(111);
```

From the information on `r(111)`:

> __________ not found;
>   no variables defined;
>   The variable does not exist.  You may have mistyped the variable's name.

What is wrong with my syntax? That is, why is Stata treating `if` as a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your definition the text `if` is part of the macro contents.

```
quietly reg y x1 x2 x3
local subset if e(sample)
list Unit `subset'
reg y x1 x2 if `subset'
```

So the `list` command works because it is interpreted as

```
list Unit if e(sample)
```

but the `regress` command is not working because it is interpreted as

```
regress y x1 x2 if if e(sample)
```

and Stata is puzzled out of its mind by the second `if`.

That's a comparatively minor deal. The bigger deal is that absolutely all you are doing is putting the text `if e(sample)` into the local macro `subset` and saving yourself a few characters in typing. That is fragile because, come the next estimation command, with possibly a different estimation sample, the local macro won't have the same implication. There is a better way to keep track securely of the estimation sample, which is to create an indicator immediately after model estimation by e.g.

```
gen byte regsample = e(sample)
```

and then `if regsample` is guaranteed to select precisely the same subset (including all the observations whenever they were all used).

Answer (score 5):

Your immediate problem is that you have a double `if`. The local macro `subset' contains the string "if e(sample)", so when Stata is interpreting the line:

```
reg y x1 x2 if `subset'
```

it reads:

```
reg y x1 x2 if if e(sample)
```

---

The more important problem is that this method is very fragile as the contents of `e(sample)` will be overwritten by every estimation command. It is probably safer to do something like this:

```
quietly reg y x1 x2 x3
gen byte touse = e(sample)
reg y x1 x2 if touse
```

This will create a variable, which will not be overwritten by future estimation commands, that contains a 1 when you want to use that observation (hence the name) and 0 when you don't want to use that observation. Since 1s are treated as "true" and 0s as "false", the statement `if touse` selects the observations you want to use.